# Change my name on Google

Tags: google-account

I've had my Gmail account for years and years. I wanted to change my name to match an identity (blog) which I've been building for years but Google won't let me do it. Is there any workaround?

Google will let me build Google+ pages with the name that I want to use, but it won't let me change my name in my default account.

Comment: you are talking about your 'Display name'? or you wanna change your 'email' address?

Comment: "Google won't let me do it" - how? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Google+ About page. It should look something like the following URL:

```
https://plus.google.com/+YourName/about
```

Now simply click on your name, and you will be presented with an option to change your name. In my experience changing this name will change your name across any of your Google accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your display name (as per the post below about using the G+ account name, or by going into your Blogger profile and changing it there if you are not using Google+).

But you cannot change your underlying google account name if it is a gmail-name, eg    john.doe@gmail.com

One option is to set up a new Google account with a name that matches the blog's name, and transfer ownership of the blog to this new account.   To transfer ownership, first you give the new account author rights, then upgrade it to be an administrator.

If you do choose to use the ownership transfer approach, be aware that you may have many other things to change (comments notification, photo ownership, etc).    You need to consider how your blog is set up and what is required:- I've outlined as many potential issues as i've found here:   http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2010/01/transferring-blog-ownership.html